# Health/readiness probes for Azure App Services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-load-balancer

I have app service with several scaled out-rules predefined, when load balancer routing my request I want to be able to configure health/readiness probes for my application (not the server itself), is it achievable? If not, what workarounds can be applied?

Comment: you can configure custom probes at the LB level. did you try that option ?

Comment: @Aravind maybe I missunderstood something, but how can I access LB? When I create scale our rules, LB created under the hood, so I cannot see it, at least that's my knowledge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the Azure app service is a managed service by the Azure platform. It is an HTTP-based service for hosting web applications, REST APIs, and mobile back ends without having to explicitly provision or manage infrastructure. So, I don't think you can have more control of load balancing power for app service.

However, if you directly host your application on the underlying infrastructure like VM or VMSS behind of a [Azure load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview#skus), you can directly set the health probe for your backend instance via probe a port on a backend endpoint that reflects the health of that instance and the application service you are providing. You could get more details from [design guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview#design).

Additionally, if you sick on app service, you still can have multiple choices for load-balancing services. You need to add the Layer 7 load balancers that only accept HTTP(S) traffic like Azure front door or Azure application gateway in front of your app service.

- [Application Gateway health monitoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview)
- [How Front Door determines backend health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-health-probes)

For more references, you could read the [overview of load-balancing options in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview).